# Please, add Hats in the android app!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app, winter-bash-2013

Hats are lovely. They are fun!

Can we have them in the Android app too, as a Christmas present?
(current app version: 0.1.74)

Comment: It's only there for two weeks. Not sure if it' worth the dev time to push hats to an alpha testing environment where only a few folks will ever use it.

Comment: Also, mobile is meant to be fast with minimal load. IIRC the mobile site doesn't have hats either.

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish app and mobile are totally different beasts... who knows maybe adding hats to the app is simple enough. We can always hope!

Comment: Good point; personally, I like them and they are a recurring feat on stackexchange. I'd love to see them added, but it is probably a very low-priority task

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish they could be downloaded in the background and cached, for example... (just an idea)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd AFAICT it would be easier to do this to the mobile site than the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mr. Peanut Monopoly McManish a.k.a. Manishearth is spot-on with his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212049/please-add-hats-in-the-android-app#comment682013_212049).

> Not sure if it' worth the dev time to push hats to an alpha testing environment where only a few folks will ever use it.

Nope, not worth it. Sorry.

Comment: Fair enough :) I tried. Merry Christmas!