# Please show hats in the Android app (aka android app hates hats)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, winter-bash

I don't hate hats. Proof:

[image: I HAZ MAH HATZ ON]

Yet, the Android app isn't showing them:

[image: Y U NO HATZ??]

Saw [this post from 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212049/197901) asking for hats in the Android app, and [this one from 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245206/197901), also saying essentially "it's not worth it".

Fine.

Except, the iFolks got their hats on this year:

[image: iHat]

That's *religion-based* discrimination (totally! don't deny it!) and I demand nothing but fairness.

All apps should be born equal.

Comment: Which is ironic, because Google is an organisation that wears many hats.

Comment: Android app is the little, neglected, brother of the iOS app who gets all the attention and resources. No idea why, but agree it's highly frustrating.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you mean *but iAgree it's highly frustrating* =)

Comment: Ooooo that's me! How exciting. I look way better in a hat than you @Mat'sMug

Comment: @SexyTurnip that's fine, I have more hats than you do anyway mwahahahaha!

Comment: Well with a laugh as evil as that I wouldn't be surprised if you stole your hat collection ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 26):

I'm really sorry we don't have anything on Android :( I promise the Android app *does* love fun, its parents just didn't have any time to help it dress up.

Ironically, I was too busy wearing too many hats myself to be able to work on this. Brian implemented it on iOS very quickly, so my initial hope was to wait for him to figure out the hard stuff then just copy it but I just didn't have any time.

Internally we use GitLab to help with our git flow, here's a heatmap of my commits over the last year, as you can see, as we get closer to the end of the year I seem to be dying (and/or committing less and less), which gives less bandwidth to be able to work on fun stuff for my baby.

[image]

Comment: (I really don't want to stick a [tag:status-declined] on this)

Comment: If you're waiting for Brian to make it, you could stick [meta-tag:status-deferred] on it :-)

Comment: Next year we'll get balpha to add shoes in addition to hats to give you a little extra encouragement

Comment: I'm going to have to reject this reasoning because your commits don't spell anything nerdy or make a pretty picture. This lack of commitment (ha...get it? "commit"ment) shouldn't be tolerated for something as important as this. In good news, 2016 is approaching. I trust you'll do better next year. :)

Comment: Ping! Just checking to see if Winter Bash 2016 will rock on Android too this year (it's still time to start working on it, right?)... any news? =)

Comment: @Meta'sMug great timing!! I should have ample time to make sure Android celebrates this year too.

Comment: Not to rush you or anything, but there's only a little over 350,000 seconds left. Still plenty of time? ;-)

Comment: @Meta'sMug Until about an hour ago I was dedicating my three day weekend to it but I'm gonna have to admit defeat :( I ended up needing to spend way more time testing out different SVG parsing libraries than I expected.

Comment: As someone whose just gone and installed the SO app on an old tablet (I'm old school my mobile is for calls and SMS only!) just to get the 7 app vote headwear, I can't say I'm particularly whelmed by the app.  Fair enough I'm using Android 4.1 but for it to keep crashing to the 'desktop' is not helping and then to find I'm not able to wear my choice of head ware - I'm devastated, hope things get fixed for next year...