# Do we receive hat notifications on the Android mobile app?

Tags: support, android-app, winter-bash

I know hats are not enabled in the Android app, but is there a way to receive notifications when you have earned one? Similar to when you get a comment or other notification, just for hats, or has the app been left entirely normal this year?

Comment: Well, seeing as this has been so controversial, go ahead and DV me a few more times so I get a hat :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, apparently [the Android App hates hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270863/197901), and with Winter Bash notifications being in their own little snowflake menu, the answer is "nope".

(posted from my Android phone)