# Why Winter Bash details are not updated in Android App

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

Why Winter Bash details are not updated in Android App.

Even there are hats for using app.

Details such as :

1. How many hats
2. How many i gained

Etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because <s>the Android app hates</s> hats.

> *[[...] I was too busy wearing too many hats myself to be able to work on this. Brian implemented it on iOS very quickly, so my initial hope was to wait for him to figure out the hard stuff then just copy it but I just didn't have any time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270885/197901)*

Give it 6 to 8 weeks.