# StackExchange.com hates hats!

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, winter-bash

My network profile on StackExchange.com has no hats...

[image: Profile picture without hat]

## I can haz hats?

Comment: Wait, I fail to see how it's a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270863/android-app-hates-hats. Don't get the dupe votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasons http://stackexchange.com does actually hate hats are, I guess, following:

- you can wear different hats on different sites
- you don't choose to wear a separate hat on the http://stackexchange.com itself, as you don't post there and hence can't show it off :)

Comment: On the contrary the default option is apply to all sites, which suggests you can apply it to *all* sites

Comment: @angussidney And what if you don't? What if you apply one hat on one site, and a different on another? What hat will be shown in the network profile?